# Token used to prove id when clicking on confirmation e-mail. Want token to be reusable after time elapsed

Tags: php, email, get, registration, token

I'm creating a website where a confirmation e-mail will be sent out after a user registers. I want to have it so that the page will expire after a few days and the token can be reused.

So in detail the user will receive an e-mail containing a link to a webpage. This link will pass data by GET to the webpage, and this data will be "the token" which proves the identity of the user. I was considering using the PHP function [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) but that wouldn't allow the reuse of tokens and I don't like it for other reasons. What's a better approach? I'm very open to ideas and if someone can think of a better way of authenticating accounts and limiting it to a few days please share!

Is the name "token" correct in this context or is it called something else?

EDIT: I guess I'm open to using things like `uniqid()` but wouldn't it produce and easily guessable token?

Comment: No, it's not secure at all. The least thing you could do is take, if you would like, uniqid(), add some salting and hash it with, for example, sha256 or something. Then store it in a table with a expiry date for and look it up when it's requested. The odds someone will guess a valid token is very small. On top you could add some sort of logging to prevent people from flooding your system with attempts to find a valid token or slow down the lookup so it takes several seconds making it less interesting to do a brute-force lookup attempt.

Comment: So that's why I don't want to use `uniqid()`. I'm thinking of inventing my own tokens and randomly choose from the list of available ones.

Comment: But even if you generate millions unique tokens you are way, way, way beyond the security of uniqueid() or the setup I provided. Uniqueid gives you 1.40676848e+11 combinations (if I'm correct) and giving the more_entropy param 5.30987822e+15 combinations. I would advise you strongly NOT to work with a pre-calculated set of hashing. This will be your weak spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to reuse a token anyway? But in general I would setup a table like:

```
token_id (varchar 75)
expiry_date (date field)
```

And then lookup the token when requested. The expired tokens can be removed using, for example, a cron that runs daily. When generating a new token I would validate it against the existing token_id's to prevent duplicates.

By running a cron you 'cleanup' old tokens to make room for re-use. Although if you generate a 75 char hash the odds of duplicate tokens are minimal (depending on the number of tokens generated daily of course).

Comment: How do you know the length of the id is going to be 75?

Comment: Just a guess. Alter to requirements. A sha256() for example requires, you guess it, 256 chars. But for most uses 75 chars is some sort of default length.